# Shared folder access in LAN between Ubuntu 9.10 and Windows XP

Tags: networking, 9.10, windows-xp

In my home , I am have 3 machines and all are in LAN. Out of 3 , one machine is windows loaded and i need to get the shared folders from windows from my Ubuntu 9.10.

Previously i had accessed the windows shared files(through smbclient) from my Ubuntu 8.10, but in newer version i can't able to do that.

How can view the shared files in GUI/shell from Ubuntu (samba client or any other mechanisms?)

Answer (score 4):

Personally I just stick `smb://windows_address/share_name` in Nautilus's address bar (click the pencil or press control+l)

You can also browse the available network through Places -> Network.

Comment: Yeah, Places -> Network or the Network item in the Nautilus sidebar are the easiest ways to get there.

Comment: No i can't access through this.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use Places > Connect to Server and input the information about the server. You can bookmark a connection so you can initiate in a single click afterwards.

Another, probably more robust method is using CIFS to mount the share. You can use this method to even make a permanent mount. That requires a bit more reading which you can do here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MountWindowsSharesPermanently

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it is not the linux machine that is the problem. Try rerunning the "Connect to a network"-wizard and make sure filesharing is enabled. If it is already enabled, try disabling it, finishing the guide, then running the guide again and reenabling it.

If that setting is unenabled, the shares are inaccessible.

/B2S